# Word order in an example

Tags: phrase-usage, word-order, perfect-constructions

My system requires the temperature to be deviated from the baseline for X seconds in order to become activated.
Could I say that X:

> Specifies the number of seconds for which the temperature has to be
>   deviated from the baseline for the activation of the system.

I am not sure whether it is correct as it is or some perfect tense should be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes sense, but is a bit more complicated that necessary.
I suggest changing the passive voice to active, both for clarity & brevity.

> My system requires the temperature to deviate from the baseline for X seconds in order to activate.

Or

> For my system to activate, the temperature must deviate from the baseline for X seconds.

Or

> The system activates once the temperature deviates from the baseline for X seconds.

For the 2nd sentence:

> "X" specifies the number of seconds for which the temperature has to deviate from the baseline in order to activate the system.

Shorter passive alternatives:

> Once the temperature deviates from the baseline for X seconds or more the system is activated.

Or

> The system is activated once the temperature deviates from the baseline for X seconds.